# Swift(UI) Error: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable

Tags: swift, swiftui, mutable

Basically what i want to do is if you press the Button then entries should get a new CEntry. It would be nice if someone could help me out. Thanks!

```
struct AView: View {

   var entries = [CEntries]()

   var body: some View {
       ZStack {
           VStack {
               Text("Hello")
               ScrollView{
                   ForEach(entries) { entry in
                       VStack{
                        Text(entry.string1)
                        Text(entry.string2)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Button(action: {
            self.entries.append(CEntries(string1: "he", string2: "lp")) <-- Error
        }) {
            someButtonStyle()
        }
    }
}
```

}

---

### The Class CEntries

```
 class CEntries: ObservableObject, Identifiable{
    @Published var string1 = ""
    @Published var string2 = ""

    init(string1: String, string2: String) {
        self.string1 = string1
        self.string2 = string2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Views are immutable in SwiftUI. You can only mutate their state, which is done by changing the properties that have a `@State` property wrapper:

```
@State var entries: [CEntries] = []
```

However, while you could do that, in your case `CEntries` is a class - i.e. a reference type - so while you could detect changes in the array of `entries` - additions and removals of elements, you won't be able to detect changes in the elements themselves, for example when `.string1` property is updated.

And it doesn't help that it's an `ObservableObject`.

Instead, change `CEntries` to be a `struct` - a value type, so that if it changes, the value itself will change:

```
struct CEntries: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = .init()
    var string1 = ""
    var string2 = ""
}

struct AView: View {

   @State var entries = [CEntries]() 

   var body: some View {
       VStack() {
          ForEach(entries) { entry in
             VStack {
                Text(entry.string1)
                Text(entry.string2)
             }
          }
          Button(action: {
            self.entries.append(CEntries(string1: "he", string2: "lp"))
          }) {
              someButtonStyle()
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.